# From table to longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I have tried to convert this table to longtable but did not succeed and am hoping that you can help. The longtable-package is loaded already.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\caption{Accepted positions.}
\label{Table:accepted}
\tiny
    \begin{threeparttable}
         \begin{tabular}{llllllll}
             \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
             Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
             \midrule
             2015 02 11.83985 & (279038) & xyz & RA & Dec & 20.3 V & 026 – Obscode & abc \\

            \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
        \end{tabular}
     \begin{tablenotes}
        \item [a] Note number 1
        \item [b] Note number 2
     \end{tablenotes}
     \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{llllllll}
\caption{Accepted positions.}
\label{Table:accepted}
    \tiny
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}
            \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
            Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead

            {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
            \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
            Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
            \midrule
            \endhead

            \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
            \multicolumn{8}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
            \endfoot

            \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
            \endlastfoot
            2015 02 11.83985 & (279038) & xyz & RA & Dec & 20.3 V & 026 – Obscode & abc \\

    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \item [a] Note number 1
        \item [b] Note number 2
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{longtable}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

It's not working. What is the solution. Without longtable - the first syntax - works just fine.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Again: What is the question? `It's not working` is not really helpful. A `\documentclass{...} ...\begin{document} ... \end{document}` would be nice too

Comment: Point taken with the MWE. But rejected concerning question. If I knew how to specify I could probably help myself already. But as that's not the case "It's not working" is the only statement that says what's going on and stands for a question.

Comment: If I would say to you: **My car -- It's not working**... what would your answer be?  `Oh sure, that must be the engine`?

Comment: As an car mechanics I would start to help you as a non-car mechanic by looking at the most frequent problems that arise with cars, instead of telling you to learn car mechanics first in order to tell me exactly where the problem is. That's what I as a professional car mechanics am here for. And now that I have provided a working MWE - at least in my compiler - I hope I can be given constructive help.

Comment: Well... yes... the basic problem with your code I see is that `threeparttable does not work inside of the `longtable` environment. You could use it outside of `longtable`, but then you will lose the page wrapping of tables then. Omitting `threeparttable` will drop the `\tnote` feature.

Comment: And for `\caption...` there must be follow a `\\\`

Comment: David Carlisle just answered it basically the same way ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The `threeparttablex` is done for that: bringing the functionalities of `threeparttable` to `longtable`. It defines a `ThreePartTable` and a `TableNotes` environments. The latter must be declared at the `beginning`  of the ThreePartTable environment, before `longtable`. It is inserted with an `\insertTableNotes` command, wherever you want.The tablenotes can be referred to. See details in the package documentation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \small
  \begin{TableNotes}
    \item [a] Note number 1
    \item [b] Note number 2
  \end{TableNotes}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}llllllll@{}}
    \caption{Accepted positions.\label{Table:accepted}}\\
    \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
    Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{8}{r}{\textit{continued}}\\
    \endfoot
    \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
    \insertTableNotes
    \endlastfoot

    2015 02 11.83985 & (279038) & xyz & RA & Dec & 20.3 V & 026 – Obscode & abc \\

  \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,abstracton]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom=3.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}[!htb]
%\centering
%\tiny
\small
%    \begin{threeparttable}
         \begin{longtable}{@{}llllllll@{}}
\caption{Accepted positions.\label{Table:accepted}}\\
             \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
             Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
             \midrule
\endfirsthead
             Date (UT) & Object & Type\tnote{a} & J2000 RA & J2000 Dec & Magn & Location\tnote{b} & Ref \\
             \midrule
\endhead
             2015 02 11.83985 & (279038) & xyz & RA & Dec & 20.3 V & 026 – Obscode & abc \\

            \cmidrule{1-8} \morecmidrules \cmidrule{1-8}
        \end{longtable}
     \begin{enumerate}
        \item [a] Note number 1
        \item [b] Note number 2
     \end{enumerate}
%     \end{threeparttable}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the `\tnote` directives inserting footnote markers?

Comment: @Mico I guess so, they didn't generate any errors:-)